# how to fetch data and display it in the same php page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I want to fetch some data from one table in the same page when a row of other table is clicked.

Here is the code for of what I am trying to do and I am stuck:

```
<?php
$db_table="area";  
$db_query='select areaid,area_name from ' . $db_table;
$query_result=mysqli_query($dbc,$db_query) or die('error querying db');?>

<div id="area1" >
    <h3>Select ony two area from Category </h3>
         <form>
             <fieldset style="float: left; width: 25%">
                  <legend>Project Area</legend>
                      <table border=1>
                         <tr> 
                            <th> </th>
                            <th> Area Name </th>
                         </tr>
                      <?php 
                        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query_result)){ 
                      ?>
                         <tr id="<?php echo $row['areaid'];?>" class="area" onlick="showfaculty()">
                              <td> <input class="selectarea" type="radio"  name = "proarea" value="<?php echo $row['areaid'];?>"></td>
                              <td> <?php echo $row['area_name']; ?></td>
                        </tr>

                        <?php }
                         echo '</table></br></br>
          </fieldset>

          <fieldset id="avaguide" style="width: 25%">
                   <legend>Available Guide</legend>
                        <table border=1>
                             <tr> 
                                <th> </th>
                                 <th> Available Guides </th>
                             </tr>';
                            $db_table2="facultytable"; 
                            $db_query='select facultyID,facultName from ' .                       $db_table2.' where project_count<2';
                            $query_result=mysqli_query($dbc,$db_query) or die('error querying db');
                            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query_result)){
                            ?>
                            <tr id="<?php echo $row['facultyID'];?>" class="area">
                                   <td> <input class="selectguide" type="radio"  name = "areaguide" value="<?php echo $row['facultyID'];?>"></td>
                                   <td> <?php echo $row['facultName']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                     <?php }        
                        echo '</table></fieldset>

                   </form>
            </div>;`
```

Now my code is working fine it shows both area and faculty table. But it displays full faculty table. What I want to do is when click the row of area table some function should be called which get the all the faculty id of the selected area id from the table faculty_area(a_id, f_id) and faculty table shows only the name of faculty with fetched faculty id. An example of that function is below.

```
function showFaculty($aeraid){
         $db_table2="faculty_area"; 
         $db_query='select f_id from ' . $db_table2.' where a_id = '.$areaid;
         $query_result=mysqli_query($dbc,$db_query) or die('error querying db');
         while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query_result)){ some code that can be used to display faculty table with feteched f_id}
```

Please tell me how can I do it.

Comment: Please make an effort to help others to understand your problem. Paste here table structures and format your text well.

Comment: and is your code is what exactly? or, are you asking US to code it for you?

Comment: **Please do NOT expect a MAGIC answer to appear below**. That isn't *"How Stack rolls"*.

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding service**

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best way to do this task is using AJAX or you can build one page application with JS and RESTful service on PHP. I like AngularJS as frontend.